# Display \LaTeX-symbol in Doxygen documentation

Tags: latex, doxygen

I would like to display the classic \LaTeX symbol in my documentation generated by Doxygen. According to the  [Doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html) the default mode when using the tags \f$ [LaTeX code here] \f$ is "math mode". But in math mode I get the following error when using
\f$\LaTeX\f$:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
             \@m {}
l.5 $\LaTeX
           $
? 
! Emergency stop.
\@->\spacefactor 
                \@m {}
l.5 $\LaTeX
           $
```

If I try this code:

```
\f{tabular}{{|l|l|l|}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & \LaTeX \\
\f}
```

I get a nice [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRbD3.png) with the correct \LaTeX symbol. This way I guess I "broke out" of math mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `\LaTeX` cannot be set as-is inside math mode. Instead, if you need to escape to math mode *or* are already in math mode due to some other reason, use

```
\mbox{\LaTeX}
```

`\mbox` - the shorthand version of `\makebox` - sets its contents in text mode.

Comment: Yes! That worked. Using Doxygen format
    \f$\mbox{\LaTeX}\f$
I finally got it working. Thank you!